# dynamically updating values using jquery in nested forms rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using nested form gem in rails. I have a field in parent form, say 'region' and a field in nested form, say 'marketplace'. My usecase is like when a particular region is selected all the corresponding marketplaces should be dynamically updated in nested forms. I have used jquery for that. Now when the page gets refreshed or when validation error throws up while submitting the form the marketplace values do not persists.. How can I implement this?

Comment: Please provide some example code of what you have so far.

Comment: More code would be highly beneficial